# WebSocket - python server is not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, websocket

I am using this Python server but its not working at all, i have tested my webSocket client is correctly sending packets but from Python its not getting anything.

Python websocket server:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
from tornado.options import define, options
define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("OK OK OK ")

def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Websocket client:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  //var wsUri = "ws://localhost:9999/";
  var wsUri = "ws://192.168.1.14:8888/";
  var output;

  function init(){
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    testWebSocket();
  }

  function testWebSocket() {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
      onOpen(evt)
    };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) {
      onClose(evt)
    };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
      onMessage(evt)
    };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) {
      onError(evt)
    };
  }

  function onOpen(evt){
    writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
    doSend("ls;pwd;cd /var/tmp;cp -R * /tmp;rm -fr /tmp/tt*;ls;pwd");
  }

  function onClose(evt){
    writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
  }

  function onMessage(evt){
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data + '</span>');
    websocket.close();
  }

  function onError(evt) {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
  }

  function doSend(message) {
    writeToScreen("SENT: " + message);
    websocket.send(message);
  }

  function writeToScreen(message) {
    var pre = document.createElement("p");
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
    pre.innerHTML = message;
    output.appendChild(pre);
  }
  window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
</script>
<h2>WebSocket Test</h2>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the websocket handler, not the request handler, try with this [example](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.1/websocket.html)

Comment: Did you found any solution? Cause its not working from Javascript to Python send and receive command using websocket.

Comment: In your paste, you have both requesthandler and websockethandler in the same path, that is not allowed, you need to serve websocket requests or plain requests on same path, try with this => http://pastebin.com/D9fqETWb

Comment: Perfectly now working. It was indeed Python server issue. thank you.